# How to catch GWT HorizontalSplitPanel double click event

Tags: events, gwt

I want to fully expand or restore a GWT HorizontalSplitPanel when the user double clicks in the panel thumb.

I was planning to extend the HorizonTalSplitPanel to add this behavior, but since it's a final class, it's not possible.

Does anybody knows a way to implement this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented something similar to DLH's suggestion, [details of which are here](http://www.malethan.com/article/gwt_horizontalsplitpanel_double_click.html)

It works great in IE, but I've been getting sporadic behaviour in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a class to wrap the HorizontalSplitPanel which would extend another panel (maybe a SimplePanel). The HorizontalSplitPanel would be a private field in the wrapper class.

Then you would add a DoubleClickHandler to the panel thumb which would call hSplitPanelObject.setSplitPosition(newPosition).

Does that seem workable?